# Seaborn Scatterplot Color by X and Y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am having trouble coloring what should be a simple scatter plot. I am plotting two comparing columns in my pandas data frame, but I would like to color the scatter plot by X scatter and by Y scatter. So X scatter would be red and Y scatter will be black.

Here is a snippet of what I have done so far. This is with sns.lmplot, but I have tried with sns.scatterplot also.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

x=df_layer10s2['xco2'].values
y=df_layer10s2['xco2_part'].values
col = (if x then 'r', else 'black')
ax= sns.lmplot(x='xco2',y='xco2_part',data=df_layer10s2)
# plt.ylim(389,404)
# plt.xlim(389,404)
```

also here is a image of how my dataframe is set up:

[image]

Comment: you are plotting y vs x.. what do you mean by "X scatter would be red and Y scatter will be black" ? You need a third variable to provide the color right?

Comment: Right, but I basically just want where each scatter is coming from. Like red scatters would be the X value representing the XCO2 and black would be the Y value representing the XCO_part. I’m not sure if that makes sense. I don’t want to involve a 3rd variable, I just want to show the comparison between the two columns.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing the parameters of `lmplot`. Also, you could use `regplot` instead, as your not using the features that make `lmplot` different from `regplot`. Regardless, it seems you should be using your `'time'` column as your x-values and `'xco2'` and `'xco2_part'` as y-values. In this case, you can make two plotting calls and set your `color` parameter. So something like this:

```
sns.regplot(x='time', y='xco2', data=df_layer10s2, color='r')
sns.regplot(x='time', y='xco2_part', data=df_layer10s2, color='k')
```

Here's an example:

```
np.random.seed(42)
time = np.random.random(50)
y0 = np.random.random(50)
y1 = np.random.random(50)
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'y0': y0, 'y1': y1})

sns.regplot(x='time', y='y0', data=df, color='r')
sns.regplot(x='time', y='y1', data=df, color='k')
```

[image]

Comment: I have plots like this already. The main thing I'm looking to do is be able to tell what scatter point is coming from which model (either XCO2 or XCO2 part.) It would be better almost if I could just change the marker shape of the scatter to which model they come from. I think my question is unclear.

Comment: I'm confused about what you want then. The different colors will tell you where the data point is coming from: red for xco2 and black for xco2 part (for instance), which is what I understand your original question to be also. Would you rather have different markers now?